# Convolution of a piecewise function with itself

Tags: convolution

[Convolution of a function with itself](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1173103/convolution-of-a-function-with-itself) I was going through this question. In the answer, the limits of the integral was transformed from (-infinity)-(+infinity) to 0 to x. Can anyone explain how this happened?

Comment: They used the fact that the function is zero outside of $[0,1]$.

Comment: @CameronWilliams In the first case, when $x$ is between 0 and 1, how did they come up with the limits of $0$ and $x$?

Answer (score 2):

The function is non-zero only in $[0,1]$. So, for the convolution to be non-zero you need $$ 0 < x - y < 1 \implies x-1<y<x \ $$ $$ \ \text{and} \ 0<y<1.$$ If $0<x<1$ then clearly $$0<y<x$$ has to hold by the two inequalities above.